# How to add title to and avatar in octobercms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-widgets

I noticed that if you click on the avatar in the backend you can add a title an description but when I do it does not save either I Have looked through the documents but can not find a method to save this information and how to access this information, you have the same behavior for files uploaded to the backend I would like to utilize this feature if possible. This is what is echoed out

```js
{
    "id": 23,
    "disk_name": "5f29c6cd94e57384113678.pdf",
    "file_name": "instructions_for_use.pdf",
    "file_size": 388398,
    "content_type": "application/pdf",
    "title": null,
    "description": null,
    "field": "pdf",
    "sort_order": 23,
    "created_at": "2020-08-04 20:36:29",
    "updated_at": "2020-08-04 20:36:32",
    "path": "http://test.test/storage/app/uploads/public/5f2/9c6/cd9/5f29c6cd94e57384113678.pdf",
    "extension": "pdf"
}
```

description but can not find method to store the title field

Answer (score 0):

adding title and description to avatar, Its working,

Its file's title and description attribute.

if you are using `attachments $attachOne $attachMany` you can also use this attributes.

> https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments

This are normal attributes if you want to set it you can easily set them directly

### For ex:

---

```php
// if you have relation like this 
public $attachOne = [
    'avatar' => 'System\Models\File'
];


// create file instance
$file = new System\Models\File;
$file->data = Input::file('file_input');
$file->is_public = true;

// you can directly set them
$file->title = 'some title';
$file->description = 'some description';

$file->save();

// your $model using avatar relation
$model->avatar = $file;
$model->save();

// now you can use it directly
$echo $model->avatar->title; // -> some title
```

> Check for more references
> Docs
> https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/modules/system/models/File.php

> Github table schema `system_files`
> https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/modules/system/database/migrations/2013_10_01_000002_Db_System_Files.php

if any doubt please comment.